# Как указать размер маршаллируемого массива в структуре, если размер содержится в одном из полей?

Tags: c#, com, pinvoke, c#-7.3

Есть структура:

```
typedef struct DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS
{
    UINT DirtyRectsCount;
    /* [annotation] */ 
    _Field_size_full_opt_(DirtyRectsCount)  RECT *pDirtyRects;
    RECT *pScrollRect;
    POINT *pScrollOffset;
} DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS;
```

И я ее хочу перенести в `.NET`, но мне не понятно как определить поле `pDirtyRects`, если с константным массивом проблем нет, то разве я могу это сделать вот так?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PresentParameters
{
    public uint DirtyRectsCount { get; set; }
    [field: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeParamIndex = 0)]
    public Rect[] DirtyRects { get; set; }
    [field: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public Rect ScrollRect { get; set; }
    [field: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public Point ScrollOffset { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, проще будет написать wrapper на C++/CLI.

Comment: Что именно вы делаете? Может, не делать всё с нуля, а взять готовую библиотеку для работы с DirectX? Например, SharpDX. Или вообще Unity3D.

Comment: Нет, мне не интересны ни враппер на c++/cli, ни `SharpDX`, ни юнити, мне интересно как это делается, думаю пригодится для знаний.